# Django two models with many-to-many relation print on template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have category and product models. These have a many-to-many relation.

My models

```
class ProductCategories(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'ProductCategories')
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField()


class Product(models.Model):

    category = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategories)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()
    options = models.TextField()
    tags = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    stock_number = models.IntegerField()
    is_available = models.BooleanField()
```

My view

```
def category(request):

    categories = ProductCategories.objects.all()

    products = Product.objects.none()
    for category in categories:

        products = products.union(Product.objects.filter(category = category)[:4])

    return render(request, 'shop/shopping.html', {'categories' : categories, 'products' : products})
```

My Html

```
{% for category in categories %}
<div class="row">
    <h3 style="padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px">{% filter upper %}{{ category.name }}{% endfilter %}</h3>
 </div>

 <div class="row">

 {% for product in products %}

     {{ product.category }}

 {% endfor %}
 </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

I would like to list categories. Under each category, 4 products will be listed.

is it possible to pass queryset which includes both products and their categories?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
def category(request):    
    categories = ProductCategories.objects.all()              
    return render(request, 'shop/shopping.html', {'categories' : categories})
```

And the template

```
{% for category in categories %}

    {% for product in category.product_set.all|slice:":4" %}

        {{ product.name }}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```